# HTML file would not compile

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, css-selectors

I want to make a typewriter affect using JavaScript\ for my personal website. I found a template of this online and used the exact template to make some changes and edit it. However, it would not compile on another ide for example `repl.it`. I believe there is something wrong with the html file code, and I am not able to figure out what's wrong since I am new to html.

Here on this IDE, it works:

[image]
HTML FILE:

```
body /*What do I put here to make this html code run properly?*/
p.typeIt
```

CSS FILE:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: seagreen;
}
body p {
  color: bisque;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: opens sans, helvetica;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

JS FILE:

```
!(function (t, e) {
  "use strict";
  var i = t(document);
  (t.fn.typeIt = function (i) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var s = t(this),
        h = s.data("typeit");
      h !== e &&
        (clearTimeout(h.tTO), clearTimeout(h.dTO), s.removeData("typeit")),
        s.data("typeit", new t.typeIt(s, i));
    });
  }),
    (t.typeIt = function (i, s) {
      (this.d = {
        strings: [],
        speed: 100,
        deleteSpeed: e,
        lifeLike: !0,
        cursor: !0,
        cursorSpeed: 1e3,
        breakLines: !0,
        breakDelay: 750,
        deleteDelay: 750,
        startDelay: 250,
        startDelete: !1,
        loop: !1,
        loopDelay: 750,
        html: !0,
        autoStart: !0,
        callback: function () { }
      }),
        (this.queue = []),
        (this.queueIndex = 0),
        (this.hasStarted = !1),
        (this.inTag = !1),
        (this.stringsToDelete = ""),
        (this.style =
          'style="display:inline;position:relative;font:inherit;color:inherit;"'),
        (this.s = t.extend({}, this.d, s)),
        (this.el = i),
        this._init();
    }),
    (t.typeIt.prototype = {
      _init: function () {
        this.el.find(".ti-container, .ti-cursor, .ti-placeholder").remove(),
          this._elCheck(),
          (this.s.strings = this._toArray(this.s.strings)),
          this.el.html(
            '<i class="ti-placeholder" style="display:inline-block;width:0;line-height:0;overflow:hidden;">.</i><span ' +
            this.style +
            ' class="ti-container"></span>'
          ),
          (this.tel = this.el.find("span")),
          (this.insert = function (t) {
            this.tel.append(t);
          }),
          this.s.startDelete &&
          (this.tel.html(this.stringsToDelete),
            this.queue.push([this["delete"]])),
          this._generateQueue(),
          this._kickoff();
      },
      _kickoff: function () {
        this._cursor(),
          this.s.autoStart
            ? this._startQueue()
            : this._isVisible()
              ? ((this.hasStarted = !0), this._startQueue())
              : i.on(
                "scroll",
                function () {
                  this._isVisible() &&
                    !this.hasStarted &&
                    ((this.hasStarted = !0), this._startQueue());
                }.bind(this)
              );
      },
      _generateQueue: function () {
        for (var t = 0; t < this.s.strings.length; t++)
          if (
            (this.queue.push([this.type, this.s.strings[t]]),
              t < this.s.strings.length - 1)
          ) {
            var e = this.queue.length,
              i = this.s.breakLines ? this.s.breakDelay : this.s.deleteDelay;
            this.queue.push([
              this.s.breakLines ? this["break"] : this["delete"]
            ]),
              this.queue.splice(e, 0, [this.pause, i / 2]),
              this.queue.splice(e + 2, 0, [this.pause, i / 2]);
          }
      },
      _startQueue: function () {
        this._to(
          function () {
            this._executeQueue();
          }.bind(this),
          this.s.startDelay
        );
      },
      type: function (t, e) {
        (e = "undefined" == typeof e || e),
          (t = this._toArray(t)),
          e && ((t = this._rake(t)), (t = t[0])),
          (this.tTO = setTimeout(
            function () {
              if (
                (this._setPace(this),
                  this.s.html &&
                  t[0].indexOf("<") !== -1 &&
                  t[0].indexOf("</") === -1 &&
                  !this.inTag)
              ) {
                for (var e = t.length - 1; e >= 0; e--)
                  t[e].indexOf("</") !== -1 &&
                    ((this.tagCount = 1), (this.tagDuration = e));
                this._makeNode(t[0]);
              } else this._print(t[0]);
              t.splice(0, 1),
                t.length ? this.type(t, !1) : this._executeQueue();
            }.bind(this),
            this.typePace
          ));
      },
      pause: function (t) {
        (t = t === e ? this.s.breakDelay : t),
          this._to(
            function () {
              this._executeQueue();
            }.bind(this),
            t
          );
      },
      break: function () {
        this.insert("<br>"), this._executeQueue();
      },
      mergeSet: function (e) {
        (this.s = t.extend({}, this.s, e)), this._executeQueue();
      },
      _print: function (e) {
        this.inTag
          ? (t(this.tag, this.el).last().append(e),
            this.tagCount < this.tagDuration
              ? this.tagCount++
              : (this.inTag = !1))
          : this.insert(e);
      },
      delete: function (t) {
        this.deleteTimeout = setTimeout(
          function () {
            this._setPace();
            for (
              var i = this.tel.html().split(""),
              s = t === e || null === t ? i.length - 1 : t + 1,
              h = i.length - 1;
              h > -1;
              h--
            ) {
              if ((">" !== i[h] && ";" !== i[h]) || !this.s.html) {
                i.pop();
                break;
              }
              for (var n = h; n > -1; n--) {
                if ("<br>" === i.slice(n - 3, n + 1).join("")) {
                  i.splice(n - 3, 4);
                  break;
                }
                if ("&" === i[n]) {
                  i.splice(n, h - n + 1);
                  break;
                }
                if ("<" === i[n] && ">" !== i[n - 1]) {
                  if (";" === i[n - 1])
                    for (var r = n - 1; r > -1; r--)
                      if ("&" === i[r]) {
                        i.splice(r, n - r);
                        break;
                      }
                  i.splice(n - 1, 1);
                  break;
                }
              }
              break;
            }
            if (this.tel.html().indexOf("></") > -1)
              for (var a = this.tel.html().indexOf("></") - 2; a >= 0; a--)
                if ("<" === i[a]) {
                  i.splice(a, i.length - a);
                  break;
                }
            this.tel.html(i.join("")),
              s > (t === e ? 0 : 2)
                ? this["delete"](t === e ? e : t - 1)
                : this._executeQueue();
          }.bind(this),
          this.deletePace
        );
      },
      _isVisible: function () {
        var e = t(window),
          i = { top: e.scrollTop(), left: e.scrollLeft() };
        (i.right = i.left + e.width()), (i.bottom = i.top + e.height());
        var s = this.el.outerHeight(),
          h = this.el.outerWidth();
        if (!h || !s) return !1;
        var n = this.el.offset();
        (n.right = n.left + h), (n.bottom = n.top + s);
        var r = !(
          i.right < n.left ||
          i.left > n.right ||
          i.bottom < n.top ||
          i.top > n.bottom
        );
        if (!r) return !1;
        var a = {
          top: Math.min(1, (n.bottom - i.top) / s),
          bottom: Math.min(1, (i.bottom - n.top) / s),
          left: Math.min(1, (n.right - i.left) / h),
          right: Math.min(1, (i.right - n.left) / h)
        };
        return a.left * a.right >= 1 && a.top * a.bottom >= 1;
      },
      _executeQueue: function () {
        if (this.queueIndex < this.queue.length) {
          var t = this.queue[this.queueIndex];
          this.queueIndex++ ,
            this.isLooping && 1 === this.queueIndex
              ? this._to(
                function () {
                  t[0].bind(this)(t[1]);
                }.bind(this),
                this.s.loopDelay / 2
              )
              : t[0].bind(this)(t[1]);
        } else
          this.s.loop
            ? ((this.queueIndex = 0),
              (this.isLooping = !0),
              this._to(
                function () {
                  this["delete"]();
                }.bind(this),
                this.s.loopDelay / 2
              ))
            : this.s.callback();
      },
      _to: function (t, e) {
        setTimeout(
          function () {
            t();
          }.bind(this),
          e
        );
      },
      _elCheck: function () {
        !this.s.startDelete &&
          this.el.html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "").length > 0
          ? (this.s.strings = this.el.html().trim())
          : this.s.startDelete && (this.stringsToDelete = this.el.html());
      },
      _toArray: function (t) {
        return t.constructor === Array ? t.slice(0) : t.split("<br>");
      },
      _cursor: function () {
        if (this.s.cursor) {
          this.el.append("<span " + this.style + 'class="ti-cursor">|</span>');
          var t = this.s.cursorSpeed,
            e = this;
          !(function i() {
            e.el
              .find(".ti-cursor")
              .fadeTo(t / 2, 0)
              .fadeTo(t / 2, 1),
              e._to(i, t);
          })();
        }
      },
      _setPace: function () {
        var t = this.s.speed,
          i = this.s.deleteSpeed !== e ? this.s.deleteSpeed : this.s.speed / 3,
          s = t / 2,
          h = i / 2;
        (this.typePace = this.s.lifeLike ? this._randomInRange(t, s) : t),
          (this.deletePace = this.s.lifeLike ? this._randomInRange(i, h) : i);
      },
      _randomInRange: function (t, e) {
        return Math.abs(Math.random() * (t + e - (t - e)) + (t - e));
      },
      _rake: function (t) {
        for (var e = 0; e < t.length; e++)
          if (((t[e] = t[e].split("")), this.s.html)) {
            this.tPos = [];
            for (var i, s = this.tPos, h = !1, n = 0; n < t[e].length; n++)
              ("<" !== t[e][n] && "&" !== t[e][n]) ||
                ((s[0] = n), (h = "&" === t[e][n])),
                (">" === t[e][n] || (";" === t[e][n] && h)) &&
                ((s[1] = n),
                  (n = 0),
                  (i = t[e].slice(s[0], s[1] + 1).join("")),
                  t[e].splice(s[0], s[1] - s[0] + 1, i),
                  (h = !1));
          }
        return t;
      },
      _makeNode: function (e) {
        (this.tag = t(t.parseHTML(e))),
          this._print(this.tag),
          (this.inTag = !0);
      }
    }),
    (t.fn.tiType = function (s) {
      var h = t(this).data("typeit");
      return h === e ? i : (h.queue.push([h.type, s]), this);
    }),
    (t.fn.tiDelete = function (s) {
      var h = t(this).data("typeit");
      return h === e ? i : (h.queue.push([h["delete"], s]), this);
    }),
    (t.fn.tiPause = function (s) {
      var h = t(this).data("typeit");
      return h === e ? i : (h.queue.push([h.pause, s]), this);
    }),
    (t.fn.tiBreak = function () {
      var s = t(this).data("typeit");
      return s === e ? i : (s.queue.push([s["break"]]), this);
    }),
    (t.fn.tiSettings = function (s) {
      var h = t(this).data("typeit");
      return h === e ? i : (h.queue.push([h.mergeSet, s]), this);
    });
})(jQuery);

$(".typeIt")
  .typeIt({
    speed: 100,
    autoStart: false
  })
  .tiType("Hi,")
  .tiPause(600)
  .tiType(" My name is Gazi Taufiq.")
  .tiBreak()
  .tiPause(1000)
  .tiSettings({ speed: 300 })
  .tiType("I am a")
  .tiSettings({ speed: 75 })
  .tiType(" Web Developer")
  .tiPause(800)
  .tiDelete(15)
  .tiType("an Artist")
  .tiPause(1200)
  .tiDelete(8)
  .tiType(" Coder.")
  .tiPause(2000)
  .tiDelete()
  .tiType("Feel free to contact me")
  .tiPause(600)
  .tiType(" and we may work together. ")
  .tiPause(600)
  .tiType(":)");
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: But, you know, _HTML file would not compile_, indeed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If your IDE is reporting a JavaScript error in one specific line, you don't need you share what appears to be your complete application. Also, please avoid sharing pictures of code: text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You put arrows around `body`, put an opening and closing parenthesis at the end of `p.typeIt`, and put a `<script>` tag above (or below too, but you need a slash (`/`) character before the script tag on the bottom) `p.typeIt()`.

I think almost all HTML tags have arrows behind and in front of them.